# How to pass null to method that expects long or int?

Tags: java

Could be dumb question, but how can I pass `null` to method which takes `long` or `int`?

**Example:**

```
TestClass{
  public void iTakeLong(long id);
  public void iTakeInt(int id);
}
```

now how can i pass null to both methos:

```
TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
testClass.iTakeLong(null); // Compilation error : expected long, got null
testClass.iTakeInt(null);   // Compilation error : expected int, got null
```

Thoughts, suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to pass nulls to such a method? What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The problem is that `int` and `long` are primitives.  You can't pass `null` to a primitive value.

You can certainly use the wrapper classes `Integer` and `Long` instead of `long` and `int` in your method signature.

Comment: So, the short answer: you can't.

Answer (score 12):

You can't - there's no such value. If you can change the method signature, you can make it take a reference type instead though. Java provides an immutable "wrapper" class for each primitive class:

```
class TestClass {
  public void iTakeLong(Long id);
  public void iTakeInt(Integer id);
}
```

Now you can pass a null reference *or* a reference to an instance of the wrapper type. Autoboxing will allow you to write:

```
iTakeInt(5);
```

Within the method, you can write:

```
if (id != null) {
    doSomethingWith(id.intValue());
}
```

or use automatic unboxing:

```
if (id != null) {
    doSomethingWith(id); // Equivalent to the code above
}
```

Comment: can't change that method as there are tightly coupled implementation based on that method.

Comment: @Rachel: Then you can't pass null, it's as simple as that. There are 2^32 values for an `int` - you're trying to introduce an extra one. There aren't enough bits in an `int` value to represent that.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes, i will have to change some of my design to make that I do null check before calling this function.

Answer (score 8):

You can cast null to the non-primitive wrapper class, which will compile.

```
TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
testClass.iTakeLong( (Long)null); // Compiles
testClass.iTakeInt( (Integer)null);   // Compiles
```

But, this will throw a `NullPointerException` when executed. Not much help, but it is useful to know that you can pass the wrapper equivalent to a method that takes a primitive as an argument.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how many such methods you have, and how many calls, you have another choice.

Instead of distributing null checks throughout your codebase, you can write wrapper *methods* (N.B., not the type wrappers (int => Integer), but methods which wrap yours):

```
public void iTakeLong(Long val) {
    if (val == null) { 
        // Do whatever is appropriate here... throwing an exception would work
    } else {
        iTakeLong(val.longValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the Wrapper classes:

```
 TestClass{
    public void iTakeLong(Long id);
    public void iTakeInt(Integer id);
    public void iTakeLong(long id);
    public void iTakeInt(int id);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that. Primitive types can't be `null` in Java.

If you want to pass `null` you have to change your method signature to

```
public void iTakeLong(Long id);
public void iTakeInt(Integer id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Typecasting the value to `Long` as below will make the compilation error to disappear but eventually will end up in `NullPointerException`.

```
testClass.iTakeLong((Long)null)
```

One solution is to use type `Long` instead of primitive `long`.

```
public void iTakeLong(Long param) { }
```

Other solution is to use the `org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils`

```
testClass.iTakeLong(NumberUtils.toLong(null))
```