# passing null value as a parameter in java

Tags: java, android

i have a method to insert datas into an sq-lite db

```
 public long InsertDetails(int Id,String BatchName,double Weight,
        double Yield)
{
    ContentValues InsertContentValues = AssesmentInsertValues(Id,BatchName,Weight,Yield);
    return this.data.insert("tb_LabAssessment", null, InsertContentValues);
}
```

from my main class i m passing values as a parameter to this above function, in some cases i want to pass weight and yield as null values.

```
String batchname;
double weight;
double Yield;
dbAdapter.InsertAssesmentDetails(objClsProduct.getId(),batchname,weight,Yield)
```

how can i pass the values of weight and yield as null here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass null to method that expects long or int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389001/how-to-pass-null-to-method-that-expects-long-or-int)

Answer (score 6):

You can't pass a primitive as null.  There's two ways to do this-  first is to make the function take Double-  the class version of a double.  The other is to pass in some unused value, such as -1, to mean null.  That requires there to be a reasonable default value though.

Answer (score 2):

Change the method to:

```
public long InsertDetails(int Id, String BatchName, Double Weight, Double Yield)
```

where `Double` can hold `null`, since it's a reference type.

Comment: Autoboxing is not quite performant in Android so, you should avoid this!

Answer (score 1):

primitive types like `double` can not be null. You can send `Double` object instead. In that case in the method signature use `Double` instead of `double`. Then call the method like following

```
dbAdapter.InsertAssesmentDetails(objClsProduct.getId(),batchname,null,null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Introduce second Method with parameter you need. Passing NULL as allowed need to be documented in some way. An alternative methode makes this obsolete and you're done.